# Access a struct property by its name as a string in Swift

Tags: swift, struct

Let's say I have the following `struct` in `Swift`:

```
struct Data {
   let old: Double
   let new: Double
}
```

Now I have a class with an array of Data structs:

```
class MyClass {
   var myDataArray: [Data]
}
```

Now let's say I want to calculate the average of either the old or the new values:

```
func calculateAverage(oldOrNew: String) -> Double {
   var total = 0.0
   count = 0

   for data in myDataArray {
      total += data.oldOrNew
      count++
   }

   return total / Double(count)
}
```

And then:

```
let oldAverage = calculateAverage("old")
let newAverage = calculateAverage("new")
```

But this obviously doesn't work, since `oldOrNew` is not a member of my `struct`.

How can I access `old` or `new` from `"old"` or `"new"` ?

Comment: What should the property `oldOrNew` contain? Please provide an example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: The goal is to either access `data.old` or `data.new`, but I don't know how to pass that to my `func`.  `oldOrNew` is not a property, it is just a placeholder. I already provided an example.

Answer (score 8):

What about this "reflection-less" solution?

```
struct Data {
    let old: Double
    let new: Double

    func valueByPropertyName(name:String) -> Double {
        switch name {
        case "old": return old
        case "new": return new
        default: fatalError("Wrong property name")
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do this

```
let data = Data(old: 0, new: 1)

data.valueByPropertyName("old") // 0
data.valueByPropertyName("new") // 1
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a good solution.  Or maybe I can also just use a `Dictionary` instead of the `struct` ?

Comment: When I use this code I get the following compiler error: `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Double'` for `data.valueByPropertyName("old")`

Comment: This code does compile. Please show me the changes you did to it.

Comment: It's part of a larger Playground I'm working on, I'm sure the error is caused by that. I will check later when I'm back at my Mac.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for key-value-coding (KVC) that is accessing properties by key (path).

**Short answer**:  A `struct` does not support KVC.

If the `struct` is not mandatory in your design use a subclass of `NSObject` there you get KVC and even operators like `@avg` for free.

```
class MyData : NSObject {
  @objc let old, new: Double

  init(old:Double, new:Double) {
    self.old = old
    self.new = new
  }
}

let myDataArray : NSArray = [MyData(old: 1, new: 3), MyData(old:5, new: 9), MyData(old: 12, new: 66)]

let averageOld = myDataArray.value(forKeyPath:"@avg.old")
let averageNew = myDataArray.value(forKeyPath: "@avg.new")
```

Edit: In Swift 4 a `struct` does support Swift KVC but the operator `@avg` is not available

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't access a struct property by name in Swift any more than you would in C++. You'd provide a block.

Extemporaneous:

```
func calculateAverage(getter: (Data) -> Double) {
    ... total += getter(data) ...
}

...

calculateAverage({$0.old})
calculateAverage({$0.new})
```

Possibly with `average {$0.old}` being a more natural syntax — the verb isn't really helpful and if you're asserting what it is, not what the computer should do, then omitting the brackets looks fine.