# How can I access a struct member by passing its name as a function parameter in Swift?

Tags: swift, struct, types

(I know the question has been asked here: [Access a struct property by its name as a string in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994529/access-a-struct-property-by-its-name-as-a-string-in-swift) but I'd rather not use a switch/case statement and the struct is mandatory.)

I have a function:

```
func computeStat(_ pokemon: Pokemon,_ stat: String) {
  let level = 1
  return Int((Int(((2*pokemon.species.base_values.stat + pokemon.stat+Int(pokemon.effort_values.stat/4))*pokemon.level)/100)+5)*level)
}
```

As you can see I'd like to call the member "stat" but for different structs:

- base_values
- pokemon
- effort_values

Stat can take 5 different values (attack, defense, etc). I'm calling the function in a getter:

```
  get {
    let stats = Stats(
        hitpoints: computeHp(self),
        attack: computeStat(self, "attack"),
        defense: computeStat(self, "defense"),
        special_attack: computeStat(self, "special_attack"),
        special_defense: computeStat(self, "special_defense"),
        speed: computeStat(self, "speed")
    )

    return stats
  }
```

Of course my function, as is, doesn't work because I'm trying to access the member of a struct with a String.

Does anyone have a way to do it?

Comment: As mentioned in the linked question a `struct` does not support key-value coding. So if a struct is mandatory you need a mapping logic like a `switch` statement.

Comment: But I'd really like to avoid the `switch` since it would produce a big chunk of code for a small computation

Comment: In this case you can't have everything. Either use a **class** or add a *big chunk of code*.

Comment: All right. I would use a class but it's a university assignment and they want us to use their struct. Anyway, I guess I'll do it the long way, thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [the bottom answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34994906/2976878) to the Q&A you linked to – using a closure is the best way to go about this. In your case, you may want to consider just creating a single struct to hold your different stat values. That'll help simplify the problem – otherwise use a `protocol`.