# how to acess Struct property by name as a string in runtime in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, runtime

i have an JSON RESPONSE

```
 result: 
        [
            Result(date: "2022-04-24", abc: 1463, def: 0, ghi: 0.0), 
            Result(date: "2022-04-25", abc: 1451, def: 0, ghi: 0.0), 
            Result(date: "2022-04-26", abc: 24838, def: 100, ghi: 25.0), 
            Result(date: "2022-04-27", abc: 72833, def: 461, ghi: 115.25), 
            Result(date: "2022-04-28", abc: 31881, def: 0, ghi: 0.0), 
            Result(date: "2022-04-29", abc: 18706, def: 0, ghi: 0.0)
        ],
```

, now in my code i am using picker and have to dynamically change the key

```
**example--->** 
result.abc,
result.def,
result.ghi
```

Code where i have to dynamically change

```
HStack{
            
ForEach(downloads.indices, id: \.self){ index in
                
                if index == downloads.count-1 {
                    
                    Text("\(downloads[index].abc)")
                        .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
    
                    
                }
                
                
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
```

You can see in above code

```
downloads[index].**abc**
```

in place of this i need to change def and ghi but dhynamically

In my Home View where i call above file

```
@State var selectedScreen: [String] = ["abc","def", "ghi"]
BarGraph(downloads: dataservice.statsdetails, value: selectedScreen[pickerSelectedItem])
```

but if i pass it dynamically as a string it gives me error

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6kna.png
```

Can you help me how to solve this

Comment: You may find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994529/access-a-struct-property-by-its-name-as-a-string-in-swift

Comment: @Andrew Thanx but what my return type will be as i only have to return the property

Comment: You can't use the ForEach View with indices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward way is to add a function to your struct that returns the right value for a given key.

```
func stringProperty(for path: String) -> String {
    switch path {
    case "abc":
        return "\(abc)"
    case "def":
        return "\(def)"
    case "ghi":
        return "\(ghi)"
    default:
        fatalError("Unknown property name")
    }
}
```

Comment: let subvalue = stringProperty(for: value)
            
            ForEach(downloads.indices, id: \.self){ index in
                
                if index == downloads.count-1 {
                
                    Text("\(downloads[index].subvalue)")
                        .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    
                }
                
                
            }

it is giving me error ie. Cannot find 'stringProperty' in scope

can you tell me how i can call that function

Comment: As I said, add it to the struct (Result) and call it inside Text. `Text("(downloads[index].stringProperty(for: value)")`

Comment: one more thing, my function is returning two data type either int or double

 func intProperty(for path: String) -> Int {
        switch path {
        case "abc":
            return abc
        case "def":
            return def
        case "ghi":
            return ghi
        default:
            fatalError("Unknown property name")
        }

ghi is a double. how i can acheive this using this same function

Comment: I don't understand, this has already been done in the answer by returning a string for all types so you can use it in a `Text` component.

Comment: but this is another case i want to access the value in the property and abc and def is of int type and ghi is of double type 

so in some part of my code i need to use the value so i make intproperty function 

and now the problem is of return type 

ghi is of double so it is giving me error

i need to use the value for computaion so how can i use it now

Comment: Access the value directly? If this is another case then perhaps you should ask another question.